# Plesk : executing nodejs with pm2 / forever

Tags: node.js, plesk, pm2, forever

I read that Plesk can execute NodeJs application but I would like to know if Plesk integrates a process manager like pm2 or forever to restart automatically the node Program if it crashed ?
kaboume.

Comment: Did you find any solution ? Bcoz i am looking for this for last 3-4 days, but couldn't find anything

Comment: Finally, I removed Plesk from my server and installed all the softs (apache, node, pm2...).